# implementing a generic interface that extends from comparable

Tags: java, data-structures

```
public interface MyArray  <T extends Comparable <T>> {

T get( int i);
void set ( int i, T e);
int min ();
int max (); 
int nbBetween (T e1 , T e2);
}

public class MyArrayFactory {
    public static <T extends Comparable <T>> MyArray <T> getMyArray( int n) {
        MyArray<T> ar;
        ar = new ArrayImplentation(n);
        return ar;
    }}
```

I want to implement a generic array class having the following interface

the class MyArrayFactory which simply creates and returns an object of my
implementation of the interface MyArray.

and this is my implementation class:

```
     public class ArrayImplentation<T extends Comparable <T>> implements MyArray<T>{


    public MyArray[]arr;

    public ArrayImplentation(int n) {
        arr= (MyArray[])new Object[n];
    }

// Return the element at position i
        public T get( int i) {
        T t = (T)arr[i];
        return t;
        }
        // Set the element at position i
        public void set ( int i, T e) {
            arr[i]=(MyArray)e;
        }
        // Return the index of smallest element in the array ( index of first occurrence returned )
        public int min () {
             T minValue = (T)arr[0];
             for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
                 if(minValue.compareTo((T)arr[i])>0) {  
                 return i;
             }}
                 return 0;}
        // Return the index of largest element in the array ( index of first occurrence returned )
        public int max () {

             T maxValue = (T)arr[0];
             for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
                 if(maxValue.compareTo((T)arr[i])<0) {
                     return i;
        }}
                 return 0;}
        // Return the number of elements largest or equal e1 and smallest or equal e2
        public int nbBetween (T e1 , T e2) {
            int index=0;
            int index2=0;
            int count=0; 

            for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
             if(e1.compareTo((T)arr[i])==0)
             index=i;

            for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
             if(e2.compareTo((T)arr[i])==0) 
                 index2=i;

            for(int i=index;i<index2;i++)
                count++;

            return count;



        }

    }
```

so what should I do with implementation class to solve the problem with dealing with generic types ? class casting and a lot more
and is there a specific way to have a special compareTo method ?

Comment: So, you want to know how to allow both objects that have implemented Compareable interface, and the ones that did not?

Comment: yes I want to know what type should I declare for the array in ArrayImplementation

Answer (score 0):

If we look at how `TreeMap` does this, it may give us an idea how we can implement it:

By it's nature (of being a binary tree), `TreeMap` needs to compare keys, so that they are put correctly into a binary tree, yet the `TreeMap` class requires a key of generic type that does **not** have to implement `Compareable`. This is the declaration:

```
public class TreeMap<K,V> extends ...
```

The `TreeMap` constructor can have no arguments, or a `Comparator` argument:

```
public TreeMap() {
    comparator = null;
}

public TreeMap(Comparator<? super K> comparator) {
    this.comparator = comparator;
}
```

And it has a `compare` function it uses internally:

```
final int compare(Object k1, Object k2) {
    return comparator == null ? ((Comparable<? super K>)k1).compareTo((K)k2)
        : comparator.compare((K)k1, (K)k2);
}
```

This `compare` function explains how it works: It first tries to use the provided `comparator` object to compare two objects. If it isn't available, it assumes that the objects are comparable, and tries to compare them by using their `Comparable` implementation, by casting them into `Comparable` instances. If they're, in fact, not implementing `Comparable`, a `ClassCastException` is thrown, in which case the `TreeMap` doesn't work correctly.

So, the conclusion is that there is a way to implement a collection that can compare any two objects by providing either external or internal comparing functions, but then the generics have to have lesser restrictions, and errors can occur if not used correctly.